# How do you keep a certain number of items in a listbox

Tags: xml, vb.net

im building a weather forecast app where the user enters a location into a textbox and presses a button. the  maximum temperatures for the next 7 days must be displayed in a listbox. the xml file that i am querying has multiple nodes with the same name, theefore i have used the 'GetElementsByTagMethod' to retrieve these specific values (max temps) and added them to the listbox. now everytime the user inputs a different location and presses the button, the values in this listbox should obviously change. my problem is that while these new values do show up, they only append to values that are already there, leaving me with 14 total values. I want the new values to override the old ones on buttonclick, leaving me with 7 values at any given moment. I have already tried 'listbox.items.clear()' if 'listbox.items.count' > 7 but this just clears out all 14 values once the button is clicked for the second time, instead of clearing out the first 7 values.

```
Imports System
Imports System.xml
Imports System.net  

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument 
        Dim wclient As New WebClient
        doc.LoadXml(wclient2.DownloadString("url for the xml"))
        Dim maxtemp_c_forecast As XmlNodeList = 
        doc.GetElementsByTagName("maxtemp_c")
        For i As Integer = 0 To maxtemp_c_forecast.Count - 1
            listbox.Items.Add(maxtemp_c_forecast(i).InnerText)
        Next
    End Sub
```

I expect the listbox's 7 items to change everytime i press the button wiping the previous 7 items. for example if the user wants the forecast for new york and presses the button, the items in the listbox representing the temperature will be different to the ones that will be displayed in the listbox once the user changes the location to boston and presses the button. basically i only want 7 items in the listbox at any given moment.

Comment: Use correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability.

Comment: Where is the code for your button click event?

Comment: Clear the Listbox.Items before you add the new values.